How can I upload photo using facebook api correctly?
I've read the docs and try to make a function to upload image on facebook and get its api but it seems not work at all.
(the access token have permisson to do that request so ye)
def upload_image(token, gid, image_path):
        res = requests.post(f"https://graph.facebook.com/{gid}/photos", params={"access_token": token}, files={"source": open(image_path, "rb")})
        print(res.text)
        return res.json().get("id")

The weird part is I kept getting the error #324 (Requires upload file).

I think access_token goes to files and not to param as it seems to be expected as request body.

why access_token goes to files? files is only for files :(
